# How to refresh or reload a ViewComponent with Ajax in Asp.net Core 3.1?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I want FavoriteComponent to refresh when the "a" tag is clicked ?

Html :

```
<div id="favarite-user">
   
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("FavoriteComponent")        
</div>
```

Action Html :

```
<a id="add-fav" onclick="addfavorite('@product.Id')"></a>
```

Jquery :

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: '@Url.Action("AddFavorite", "Product")',
    data: { id: id },          
}).done(function (msg) {
    if (msg.status === 'added') {              
        $('#favarite-user').load(' #favarite-user')
    }
```

});

Controller:

```
 public IActionResult AddFavorite(Guid id)
    {           
        bool fav = _scope.AddFavorite(id, Guid.Parse(CurrentUserId));
        if (fav == true)
        {
            //return ViewComponent("FavoriteComponent");
          return Json(new { status = "added" });
        }
        return Json(new { status = "removed" });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: '@Url.Action("AddFavorite", "Product")',
    data: { id: id },          
}).done(function (msg) {
    if (msg.status === 'added') {              
        $('#favarite-user').load(' #favarite-user')
    }
});
```

Comment: is this a question or answer?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: @novonimo this is answer and qoustion...
I have some jqury code, It works when this function is not executed But it does not work after the performance

Comment: you can ask your question in the comments below the original question.

Comment: i got "the server responded with a status of 500 " error with this solution